# Changing time zone in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

If I change the time zone of my site. Will it also update the time zone of previously created content etc or should I do it through scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes , changing time zone of the site will change the time of creation to the new time zone

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Emad, My point is, will the created/changed time of current nodes be updated by just updating the timezone or do I need to update them manually through SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you change the time zone of your site, the System Time will change. If your location observes daylight saving time, such as [EST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone_%28North_America%29), your site will change to EDT during daylight saving time. [Daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight%20saving%20time) is the practice of advancing clocks. Daylight saving time allows advancing by one hour by spring and reset by autumn.